# Построчно вывод данных из базы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день )
Пытаюсь вывести данные из базы, выходит только одна и таже строка из базы.

> 01.01.2012 | сообщение1 | 0001
>
> 02.01.2012 | сообщение2 | 0002
>
> 03.01.2012 | сообщение3 | 0003

В итоге должна получиться таблица с соответствующими данными строк из базы.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testtable`");
$stats = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$row = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($row > 0){

for ($i=0;$i<$row;$i++) { /* Цикл равен - 3 */
echo "<tr>";

echo '<td><b>'.$stats['date'].'</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>'.$stats['msg'].'</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>'.$stats['num'].'</b></td>';

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></center>";

}else{  
    echo "Error!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testtable`");
while ($stats = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

$row = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($row > 0){

for ($i=0;$i<$row;$i++) { /* Цикл равен - 3 */
 echo "<tr>";

echo '<td><b>'.$stats['date'].'</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>'.$stats['msg'].'</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>'.$stats['num'].'</b></td>';

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></center>";

 }else{  
echo "Error!";
}}
```

**Добавлено из комментария.**

```
<center><table>
<?
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testtable`") or die(mysql_error());
while ($stats = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $base = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `testtable`");
    $row  = mysql_fetch_array($base);
    if ($row[0] == 0) {
        echo "empty";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td><b>" . $stats['date'] . "</b></td><td><b>" . $stats['msg'] . "    
    </b></td><td><b>" . $stats['num'] . "</b></td></tr>";
        $row = mysql_num_rows($query);
    }
}
?>
</table></center>
```

Comment: Так у меня выводится всё мимо кассы )) не в таблице
И выводится только вторая строка из базы

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Всё работает.
Можно Вас попросить прокомментировать часть кода?!

    $base = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($base);
    
    if($row[0]==0){
        echo "empty";
    }else{

Comment: а что именно? этот код подсчета если в таблице нет никаких данных выдаст: empty если есть выдаст данные

Comment: Хорошо. Сложно будет реализовать постраничный вывод информации из базы?

Comment: что тут сложного ?

Comment: Для меня построение запросов к БД. Вообще пишу на Делфи, немного знаю php, с БД сегодня связался первый раз =)

Comment: используйте всегда:
while ($stats = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){echo"bla bla bla"}
и все =)

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testtable`");
$row_count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($row_count > 0){
  echo '<center><table>';
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo ''.
      '<tr>'.
        '<td><b>'.$row['date'].'</b></td>'.
        '<td><b>'.$row['msg'].'</b></td>'.
        '<td><b>'.$row['num'].'</b></td>'.
      '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table></center>';
} else {  
  echo 'Error!';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Предоставляю простейший вариант

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testtable`");
    while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
              echo '<td><b>'.$result['date'].'</b></td>';
              echo '<td><b>'.$result['msg'].'</b></td>';
              echo '<td><b>'.$result['num'].'</b></td>';
            }
```

Comment: Сам пользуюсь не жалуюсь!